# How to make an array from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, text, bufferedreader

let me start off by saying that I am a fairly new Java programmer, and what I am trying to attempt is a bit over my head.  Thus, I came here to try to learn it.

Okay, so here's the issue:  I am trying to build a program that makes a 2d array from values in a text document.  The text document has three columns and many rows (100+)...basically a [3][i] array.

Here's what I can do:  I understand how to read the text file using bufferedReader. Here is a sample program I have that prints the text exactly how it looks in the text file (I apologize ahead for bad formatting; it's my first time on these forums):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("RA.txt"));

    String line = null;


    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] nums = line.split(",");



      for (String str : nums) {
        System.out.println(str);

      }


    }
    br.close();
  }
}
```

This is what is printed:

00 03 57.504
02 04 03.796
00 06 03.386
03 17 43.059
00 52 49.199
05 52 49.555

etc, etc.

Please help me in making an array with values. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't know in advance how many rows of data you'll have, you need to use an array of array lists. Also, I'm sure you can find some tutorial to help you. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a tutorial site. Please see the [SO Help File](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

define a list outside your while loop like

`List list = new LinkedList();`

Inside your while loop, add the splitted array to the list, like

`list.add(line.split(","));`

After the while loop convert your list to an array, resulting in a 2D array:

`Foo[] array = list.toArray(new Foo[list.size()]);`